# iText 5.4.2 and xfa

Tags: itext, xfa

So we are using a licensed iText version to set xfa into a pdf.

If we set xfa data as follows, note the xfa data tag is part of the xml. We cannot render the file using jPedal. When we view the file in Adobe we see all the fields have values.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <xfa:data xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">
     <multi>
     <firstname>1</firstname>
     <approved>1</approved>
     <groupNo>sf08</groupNo>
     <dropList/>
     <list>white</list>
     <age>age</age>
     <Title>Title</Title>
    </multi>
    </xfa:data>
```

When we checked with JPedal they said we have 2 xfa data set tags now in the pdf.

I need that xfa data tag in the xml.

Is this a iText bug?

Comment: If you are a licensed user then you have a support contract. May I ask you to that you create a ticket on the iText JIRA with one of the 3 user accounts provided to your company?

Comment: I already have done that.  Haven't heard from anyone at itext yet.

Comment: What's the issue id?

Comment: SUP-1856 - I worked around it so resolved it.  SUP-1868 and SUP-1864 are still outstanding issues.